# Getting a missing expression error in my SQL query and can't quite find out what I'm missing?

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm sure it's going to end up being something super simple and stupid but here is my query. Thank you.

```
Select Member.MemberID, Equipment.EquipmentType, Rental.RentalDate 
from Member,Equipment,Rental 
where Rental.MemberID = Member.MemberID 
  AND Rental.EquipmentID = Equipment.EquipmentID 
  AND where Rental.RentalDate in (Select RentalDate from Rental where RentalDate > '3-Mar-2021')
```

Comment: You have a second `WHERE` in there... And apart from that consider using explicit `JOIN` syntax which is found easier to read (in terms of understanding a query) and write (without errors) by most people and use table aliases and qualify all columns which, again, makes the query easier to understand and avoid errors like surprising binding.

Comment: Don't use string literals for dates as, when a user changes the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` session parameter (which any user can do at any time for their own session), then your query will fail without having made any changes to the query text. Either explicitly use `TO_DATE( '3-Mar-2021', 'DD-Mon-YYYY' )` or use a date literal `DATE '2021-03-03'`.

Answer (score 1):

there is an extra where in your query , plus always use explicit join and that last condition can be simplified as:

```
select
    Member.MemberID,Equipment.EquipmentType,Rental.RentalDate
from member
join rental
     on Rental.MemberID = Member.MemberID
     and RentalDate > '3-Mar-2021'
join equipment
     on Rental.EquipmentID = Equipment.EquipmentID
```

Comment: I knew it would be something silly, I appreciate your help